# pandas split dataframe column by slices

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I've got a fixed-width dataframe:

```
A
-------------------------------------------
BPE AED USD 2017/07/01  0_27225 1         1
BPE CLF USD 2017/07/01 40.25765 1         1
M   LBP USD 2017/07/20  0.66414 1,000     1
PF4 TRL USD 2005/01/01  0.63055 1,000,000 1
```

That needs to be:

```
A   B   C   D          E        F         G
-------------------------------------------
BPE AED USD 2017/07/01  0_27225 1         1
BPE CLF USD 2017/07/01 40.25765 1         1
M   LBP USD 2017/07/20  0.66414 1,000     1
PF4 TRL USD 2005/01/01  0.63055 1,000,000 1
```

Right now, I'm hard-coding in the slices (nums here are arbitrary):

```
df['A'], df['B'], df['C'], df['D'], df['E'], df['F'], df['G'] = df['A'].str[:4].str.strip(), df['A'].str[4:9].str.strip(), df['A'].str[9:14].str.strip(), df['A'].str[14:26].str.strip(), df['A'].str[26:36].str.strip(), df['A'].str[36:46].str.strip(), df['A'].str[46:None].str.strip()
```

But I'd like to create a function so that I can reuse it in the future, with dataframes that need to be split into a different number of columns. (This doesn't work, but) Something like:

```
headers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
slice_indices = [(0, 4), (4, 9), (9, 14), (14, 26), (26, 36), (36, 46), (46, None)]

def parse_df(headers, slice_indices, df):
     new_df = {}
     for header in headers:
         for slice in slice_indices:
             new_rows = []
             for row in df:
                fields = []
                for slice in slice_indices:
                    fields.append(row[slice[0]:slice[1]].strip())
                new_rows.append(fields)
     return new_df
```

But this seems super clunky/slow/messy to me. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You should try reading the data using pd.read_fwf() for reading the data instead of manipulating it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how does your file look like but try using the following to read the file instead of trying to slice the values later.

```
df = pd.read_fwf(file)
```

OR

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True)
```